# Rails: Unpermitted parameter with using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`Unpermitted parameter` is displayed when I try to create new data.
Althogh there are many similar questions, I can't find out how to solve.

**log**

```
Processing by SchedulesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "schedule"=>{"title"=>"test", "departure_date"=>"2016-06-24", "room"=>{"room"=>"test name"}}, "commit"=>"Create my schedule"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "schedule"=>{"title"=>"test", "departure_date"=>"2016-06-24", "room"=>{"room"=>"test name"}}, "commit"=>"Create my schedule"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: room
```

**models**

schedule.rb

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rooms, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :amounts, inverse_of: :schedule, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
```

rooms.rb

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule, inverse_of: :rooms
  has_many :events, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :amounts, inverse_of: :room, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
```

**controller**

schedule_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @schedule = Schedule.new
    room = @schedule.rooms.build
  end

  def create
    @schedule = current_user.schedules.build(schedule_params)
    if @schedule.save
      flash[:success] = "schedule created!"
      redirect_to schedule_path(@schedule)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

...

  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(
      :title, :departure_date, 
      rooms_attributes: [
        :id, :_destroy, :room, :room_address, :schedule_id, :day,  
        events_attributes: [
          :id, :_destroy, :start_at, :end_at, :title, :detail, :category,                      
          amounts_attributes: [
            :room_id, :event_id, :id, :_destroy, :ccy, :amount
          ]
        ]
      ]
    )
  end
```

**view**

/schedules/new.html.erb

```
...
<%= form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'schedule_form', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit "Create my schedule", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
...
```

/schedules/ _schedule_form.html.erb

```
...
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
...

<%= f.fields_for(:room) do |a| %>
  <%= a.text_field :room %>        #room column exist in the rooms table
<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the params in proper format

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "schedule"=>{"title"=>"test", "departure_date"=>"2016-06-24", "room"=>{"room"=>"test name"}}, "commit"=>"Create my schedule"}
Unpermitted parameter: room
```

your params should contain `rooms_attributes` instead `room`

Change `f.fields_for(:room)` to `f.fields_for(:rooms)` in `/schedules/ _schedule_form.html.erb`

```
...
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
...

<%= f.fields_for(:rooms) do |a| %>
  <%= a.text_field :room %>        #room column exist in the rooms table
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, @Deepak. I'm sorry I forgot to input my strong parameter. I add it in controller. Could you check again?

Comment: @SamuraiBlue Then the problem is in your form because you should receive oarams as `rooms_attributes` which you are not.

Try changing `f.fields_for(:rooms)`